# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() issue in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

My query in controller page

```
$d= "DB::table('users')->where('gender',$gender)";    
if(!empty($age)){
$d.= "->where('age','>',$age)";
}    
$d.="->paginate(20)";
```

if age is not empty that time only want add age to the query. but query showing Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error. Without double quotes query running but unable to avoid empty age variable.

Comment: You may want to access a variable inside `foreach()` that does not exist. If the answers below did not help you, It is better to provide more code.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version

```
 $d = DB::table('users')->where('gender',$gender); 

 $d = empty($age) ? $d->paginate(20) : $d->where('age','>',$age)->paginate(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it:

```php
$d = DB::table('users')->where('gender',$gender);    
if(! empty($age)) {
    $d = $d->where('age','>',$age);
}    
$d = $d->paginate(20);
```